# cucumber.plugin setting is generating empty report

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I tried the following command to run the cucumber test and to generate the JSON report. The cucumber test is running fine, but the report generated is empty.

```
mvn clean test -Psmoke-test -Dcucumber.plugin="pretty, json:target/cucumber/report.json"
```

The report generation is happening if I use the `@CucumberOptions` directly on the test runner class. But with the above command, it is producing empty report. Can you please check if this is correct usage

Answer (score -1):

"`-Psmoke-test` " is this correct or a typo?
Also please try using
`mvn clean verify` as your command and rather than adding `-Dcucumber.plugin="pretty, json:target/cucumber/report.json"`, you could add this in the @cucumberOptions in a runner file. Ensure to add the maven-surefire-plugin, and for reporting you could use net.masterthought plugin.
also ensure your paths are correct in the configs.
Example :

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>Sample.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: As mentioned the test is running fine. This is only about the report generation. And I also mentioned the report is indeed generating with @CucumberOptions command. My query is to understand what is the problem with the command and why that is generating only empty report.

Comment: An empty generated report means that the steps are not logged. Please share your pom, cucumber test runner and a sample test.